# Using XML annotations

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb, configuration-files

I have (inherited) an application that is configured by XML file.  When the application starts it instantiates its configuration from the file with a bunch of annotated objects.

So I have a script...

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "script")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Script {...
```

which has fields...

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "fields", required = true)
@XmlElementRef(type = Field.class)
private List<Field> fields;
```

etc.

Which is all very nice and lovely.  Now, writing the XML configuration files by hand is tedious and error-prone, so I'm thinking about writing some kind of GUI to do it.  This GUI would need to know the permitted structure so it can offer the right types of objects within the right types of objects.  All of that information is embedded within these configuration objects, and it would be wrong to have to duplicate all of this information for the GUI to know what to do.

So, extracting the information from the annotations seems like the Right thing to do.  Anyone know where to begin with something like that?  Ideally, given it includes things like `@XmlSeeAlso({...})` then it would be nice to be able to ask `javax.xml` for the information, because it might understand all its own annotations already, otherwise I'll have to encode an understanding of those in my own code.  I have no idea how feasible that is or how much I'll have to do myself.

Very happy to examine alternative approaches too, if anyone has any experience of something like this.

Answer (score 0):

> Very happy to examine alternative
>   approaches too, if anyone has any
>   experience of something like this.

You could check if you could use Spring (xml configuration) to configure your application. Normaly Spring is used for Dependency Injection, but may you could abuse it a bit.

*But this is only a idea you have to check if it matches your use case!*

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I don't think I want to change the actual underlying configuration format.  There are existing (rather large) files that would need conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB to generate an XML schema from the model objects, and then have your user interface driven by the XML schema.

**Using JAXB to Generate an XML Schema**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

**Creating a UI based on the XML Schema**

Service Data Objects (SDO) is a Java standard (JSR-235) that provides a dynamic object model with metadata that can be bootstrapped from an XML schema.  The metadata objects could be introspected to form a dynamic UI.

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-sdo.html

[EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead) provides both a JAXB and SDO implementation based on the same object-to-XML core.

Comment: Now, that looks promising.  I'll have a look at that, thanks.